# Remove ubuntu from PHP version string

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm trying removing the ubuntu (Server OS) name from PHP version

**(PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3)**

I've tried turning off the following settings in `php.ini` : `expose_php Off` -- **But didn't worked**

Tried Apache settings:

```
ServerTokens Prod // -- **But didn't worked**
ServerSignature off // -- **But didn't worked**
```

Anybody has experienced with this before please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the equals sign try this:

expose_php = off

Comment: Just checked it I'm using the = sign too

Comment: Use phpinfo(); to see if your editing the right php.ini file, and restart the server?

Comment: Already checkecd.. Have you tested you answer at your machine?